# Detect actual start of text

Tags: spacing, environments, align, enumitem, tikzmark

I have conditional which is sometimes suppressed, and if it gets typeset needs to be noted.

If the conditional text begins with an environment which adds vertical space prior to the actual start of the text, then the `\tikzmark` location needs tweaking.  Note how in paragraph mode, the text is appropriately marked, but when starting with an `align*`, or `enumerate` the brace drawn is too large:

[image]

So, what I need is to be able to detect the location of the start of the text and the end of the text, which does *not* include any leading or trailing space.

### Notes:

- Moving the `\MarkThisText` to be within an `align*` or `enumerate` won't work for me as the entire block may be suppressed, in which case I need to suppress the `begin`, `end` of the environment which would be difficult if the `\MarkThisText` didn't start until after `\begin{align*}`.
- I thought about setting a flag with an `align` and `enumerate` type environments, but that would fail if the `align` or `enumerate` happens to be embedded in the middle of `\MarkThisText`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[baseline] (#1) {};}

\newcommand{\DrawBrace}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \coordinate (Top) at 
            ($(#2.north  -| current page.south east)+(-4.5cm,0.25\baselineskip)$);
        \coordinate (Bottom) at 
            ($(#3.south -| current page.south east)+(-4.5,-0.25\baselineskip)$);
                \draw [
                    line width=1.0pt, 
                    decoration={brace, amplitude=0.30em}, 
                    decorate, #1,
                    ] (Top) -- (Bottom)
                    node[rotate=90, midway, below] {Note};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\MarkThisText}[2][]{%
    %% conditions to determine if this text is to be suppressed omitted
    %% \iftoggle{SuppressThisText}{}{%
        \tikzmark{Start}%
            \color{#1}%
            #2%
            \color{black}%
        \tikzmark{End}%
        \DrawBrace[#1]{Start}{End}%
    %% } % end \iftoggle{DisplayThisText}
}%

\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dignissim eros. 
 Morbi faucibus sit amet felis a accumsan.  Aliquam 
 dapibus pellentesque dui, vitae aliquam turpis semper eget.
 
 \MarkThisText[blue]{% 
     Donec egestas leo nibh, at malesuada leo congue non. 
     Cras laoreet lectus sed tortor laoreet, ac aliquet nibh condimentum. 
     \begin{align*}
         F &= ma \\
         \implies E &= mc^2
     \end{align*}
     Nam elementum ante non nunc facilisis porttitor. Nullam non suscipit lorem. 
     Sed arcu dui, accumsan et pretium dictum, venenatis id metus.%
 }
 
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dignissim eros. 
 Morbi faucibus sit amet felis a accumsan.  Aliquam 
 dapibus pellentesque dui, vitae aliquam turpis semper eget.


Text before \verb|align| should \emph{not} be ``noted":
 \MarkThisText[red]{% 
     \begin{align*}
         F &= ma \\
         \implies E &= mc^2
     \end{align*}
 }%
Text after \verb|align| should \emph{not} be ``noted".

Text before \verb|enumerate| should \emph{not} be ``noted":
 \MarkThisText[brown]{% 
     \begin{enumerate}
         \item List Item 1 
         \item List Item 2 
     \end{enumerate}
 }%
Text after \verb|enumerate| should \emph{not} be ``noted".
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd position the markers by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[baseline] (#1) {};}

\newcommand{\DrawBrace}[3][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \coordinate (Top) at 
            ($(#2.north  -| current page.south east)+(-4.5cm,0.25\baselineskip)$);
        \coordinate (Bottom) at 
            ($(#3.south -| current page.south east)+(-4.5,-0.25\baselineskip)$);
                \draw [
                    line width=1.0pt, 
                    decoration={brace, amplitude=0.30em}, 
                    decorate, #1,
                    ] (Top) -- (Bottom)
                    node[rotate=90, midway, below] {Note};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\MarkThisText}[2][]{%
    %% conditions to determine if this text is to be suppressed omitted
    %% \iftoggle{SuppressThisText}{}{%
    \color{#1}%
            #2%
      \color{black}%
    %% } % end \iftoggle{DisplayThisText}
}%

\newcommand\startmark[1]{\tikzmark{start#1}}
\newcommand\stopmark[1]{\tikzmark{stop#1}\DrawBrace{start#1}{stop#1}}

\begin{document}
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dignissim eros. 
 Morbi faucibus sit amet felis a accumsan.  Aliquam 
 dapibus pellentesque dui, vitae aliquam turpis semper eget.

 \MarkThisText[blue]{% 
     \startmark{a}%
     Donec egestas leo nibh, at malesuada leo congue non. 
     Cras laoreet lectus sed tortor laoreet, ac aliquet nibh condimentum. 
     \begin{align*}
         F &= ma \\
         \implies E &= mc^2
     \end{align*}
     Nam elementum ante non nunc facilisis porttitor. Nullam non suscipit lorem. 
     Sed arcu dui, accumsan et pretium dictum, venenatis id metus.%
     \stopmark{a}%
 }

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at dignissim eros. 
 Morbi faucibus sit amet felis a accumsan.  Aliquam 
 dapibus pellentesque dui, vitae aliquam turpis semper eget.


Text before \verb|align| should \emph{not} be ``noted":
 \MarkThisText[red]{% 
     \begin{align*}
         \startmark{b}F &= ma \\
         \implies E &= mc^2\stopmark{b}%
     \end{align*}
 }%
Text after \verb|align| should \emph{not} be ``noted".

Text before \verb|enumerate| should \emph{not} be ``noted":
 \MarkThisText[brown]{%
     \begin{enumerate}
         \item \startmark{c}List Item 1 
         \item List Item 2\stopmark{c} 
     \end{enumerate}
 }%
Text after \verb

|enumerate| should \emph{not} be ``noted".
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that will work for the MWE provided, but due to there also  being conditional text within the block, I don't know upfront if the environments which have surrounding space are at the beginning or end of the text to be marked.

Comment: @PeterGrill I thought the conditional omitted the entire environment and the brace, so woul domit the tikzmarks as well?

Comment: @PeterGrill although I'd put the start color in the wrong place, just moved it

Comment: Well, yeah it is in the MWE, but in my actual use there are several layers of conditions, and of course the `tikzmarks` could also be added to those conditions as well, but I'd prefer to keep the logic in `\MarkThisText` if at all possible. Perhaps using `\everypar` to set a flag and then something like `\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{if{NoParYet}{\tikzmark{Top}}}`... Just thought of this now...